# Issue in comparing double values with ISNULL

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, isnull

I am working on an assignment where I need to compare three revenue fields between two tables and when any of them are different, I need to update the value from table1 into table2.

My update query is below.

```
UPDATE OP
SET OP.CompCanceledRevenue = OPW.Comp_Canceled_Revenue__c,
    OP.PriorYearOperatingRevenueAmt = OPW.PriorYearRevenueAmount,
    OP.YTDOperatingRevenueAmt = OPW.YTDRevenueAmount,
FROM dbo.Product OP
INNER JOIN dbo.Product_Working OPW ON OPW.ProductCode = OP.ProductCode
                                   AND (OP.CompCanceledRevenue <> OPW.Comp_Canceled_Revenue__c
                                        OR OP.PriorYearOperatingRevenueAmt <> OPW.PriorYearRevenueAmount
                                        OR OP.YTDOperatingRevenueAmt <> OPW.YTDRevenueAmount)
```

When I run this query in SQL Server, I see that it is NOT pulling some records that needed to be updated where the Revenue Values are NULL in the `Product` table.

`Product_Working` table has values, but <> condition doesn't seem to work when I compare a double value with NULL. So I changed my query as below.

```
UPDATE OP
SET OP.CompCanceledRevenue = OPW.Comp_Canceled_Revenue__c,
    OP.PriorYearOperatingRevenueAmt = OPW.PriorYearRevenueAmount,
    OP.YTDOperatingRevenueAmt = OPW.YTDRevenueAmount,
FROM dbo.Product OP
INNER JOIN dbo.Product_Working OPW ON OPW.ProductCode = OP.ProductCode
                                   AND (ISNULL(OP.CompCanceledRevenue, 0) <> ISNULL(OPW.Comp_Canceled_Revenue__c, 0)
                                        OR ISNULL(OP.PriorYearOperatingRevenueAmt, 0) <> ISNULL(OPW.PriorYearRevenueAmount, 0)
                                        OR ISNULL(OP.YTDOperatingRevenueAmt, 0) <> ISNULL(OPW.YTDRevenueAmount, 0))
```

This query is returning the results that I want, but it is taking more than 1 hour to complete. The `Product` table has 500,000 rows and `Product_Working` table has about 250,000 rows. The first query returned the results in less than a minute.

Is there an alternate solution to compare the double value with NULL? Or is there a solution to make the second query run faster?

Comment: [This question and answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/168276/what-are-different-ways-to-replace-isnull-in-a-where-clause-that-uses-only-lit) touches on some alternative ways to write this. They are talking about the `WHERE` clause specifically but much of it applies.

Comment: Also, since it looks like you are trying to only update certain rows which "haven't been updated yet", you could just update all the rows. People often think this would be slower but in fact can be faster. This assumes it wouldn't change the dtaa in an unintended way..

Answer (score 4):

Seems rather obvious but each of these:

```
 ISNULL(OP.CompCanceledRevenue,0) <> ISNULL(OPW.Comp_Canceled_Revenue__c,0)
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
 (
  OP.CompCanceledRevenue <> OPW.Comp_Canceled_Revenue__c
  OR (OP.CompCanceledRevenue IS NULL AND OPW.Comp_Canceled_Revenue__c IS NOT NULL)
  OR (OP.CompCanceledRevenue IS NOT NULL AND OPW.Comp_Canceled_Revenue__c IS NULL)
 )
```

Intuitively you might expect this to be slower because it's more code, but in fact, the ISNULL function is preventing your query from using any indexes on these columns, while this longer code block will use indexes, and could therefore be faster.

Comment: Our requirement was to update only the records with different values only. If  I remove the revenue comparision criteria, it might be faster. However, it may also update several hundred thousand records unnecessary. These updates are tracked in SQL server and then pushed to Salesforce cloud and we really want to load only the changed records into Salesforce.

Comment: His answer doesn't update any more rows than your question @BalajiPooruli it just makes it SARGable

Comment: Chances are, it will still suck because `OR`s are infamously counter-productive in MS SQL. They should be rewritten as a bunch of `union all` statements.

Comment: @RogerWolf `OR` statements basically cause the parser to rewrite the query as a `UNION ALL`.  The resulting query plan is the same and while there is some overhead for the parser rewrite it's pretty small.   I wrote my example using `OR` because it's easier to read, but the principle is the same if one chooses to use `UNION ALL` instead.

Comment: @TabAlleman if wishes were horses. Unless something changed in 2017 or later versions, I never saw the optimiser to transform `OR` into the equivalent `union all` in the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1

create a 2 TEMP TABLES WITH dbo.Product OP AND dbo.Product_Working OPW. Use isnull when creating both tables

Ex.

```
Select *
      ,isnull(PriorYearOperatingRevenueAmt) as PriorYearOperatingRevenueAmt_n
      ,isnull(YTDOperatingRevenueAmt) as YTDOperatingRevenueAmt_n
into ##tmpprod
from dbo.Product
```

Do the same with both tables and join them.

Option 2 
Put your condition on a where clause

```
UPDATE OP
        SET OP.CompCanceledRevenue = OPW.Comp_Canceled_Revenue__c,
              OP.PriorYearOperatingRevenueAmt = OPW.PriorYearRevenueAmount,
              OP.YTDOperatingRevenueAmt = OPW.YTDRevenueAmount,
        FROM dbo.Product OP
        INNER JOIN dbo.Product_Working OPW 
        ON OPW.ProductCode = OP.ProductCode
Where
 ( ISNULL(OP.CompCanceledRevenue,0) <> ISNULL(OPW.Comp_Canceled_Revenue__c,0)
        OR ISNULL(OP.PriorYearOperatingRevenueAmt,0) <> ISNULL(OPW.PriorYearRevenueAmount,0)
        OR ISNULL(OP.YTDOperatingRevenueAmt,0) <> ISNULL(OPW.YTDRevenueAmount,0))
```

Comment: How would either of these be quicker?

Comment: The first one is going to be quicker because we are creating 2 temp tables with isnull operation on them this will make easier to process data by dividing the current operation on two.

Comment: Have you tested this? Inserts take time... and there will be no indexes on these temp tables (at least you haven't listed any) so the join predicate wouldn't be able to use anything but a table scan. I think you are assuming the number of records that needs updating is < half of the total records. Even so, not guaranteed to be quicker.

Comment: The number of changed records is about 30,000 in my case where Product has 500,000 records and Product_Working has 250,000 records. There are other INNER JOIN conditions that I have not listed in my query to bring down the number to around 30,000.